# A comparative clause without a subject

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Why is this comparative clause correct?

> The situation might be worse ***than seems to be.***

Does it omit the subject " that" or " it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparative clause is unacceptable in its current form.

Given that it is fairly simple and its meaning useful, it should be easy to find examples of, were it grammatical. However it's extremely rare, producing only one hit across a number of corpora (iWEB, COCA, COHA, HANSARD, SCOTUS):

> This ought to be understood more clearly **than seems to be**.
> (Comissioner Curran as quoted by the NYT 1926)

It does not seem to be the omission of the subject that causes this construction to be unacceptable as the same construction with something further after *be* produces plenty of hits.

> The pacing is sure and sharp throughout and the writing leaner **than
> seems to be the fashion these days** (The Artifacts of The Case; Paul
> Skenazy; Washington Post, 1993)
>
> These economies are providing their citizens with better tools to
> succeed **than seems to be the case in the United States today**. (A
> taxing problem; Alessi, Scott; U.S. Catholic, 2012)
>
> What is more, countries such as Zimbabwe are heavily involved in the
> South African situation and have a greater sense of realism about it
> **than seems to be apparent here**. (Mr Cuthbert Alport, House of Lords, 1989)

The three examples above, and more like them seem grammatical and accord with guidance from CaGEL p1113 on the omission of a subject from a comparative clause:

> In clauses where the verb is retained, the subject can be omitted only
> when it is the counterpart to the comparative phrase or is understood
> as an embedded clause, as in (d) above:
>
> i More people came **than were invited**. [counterpart to comparative
> phrase]
>
> ii He spent longer on it **than seemed necessary**. [embedded clause]
>
> iii *Liz works harder **than __  worked/did last year**.
>
> To remedy [iii] we must either insert a subject (she) or else omit the
> verb too, giving than last year.

The given example has an omitted subject that can be understood as an embedded clause or simple *the situation* like (iii) above:

> The situation might be worse than (it) seems to be (that the situation
> is)
>
> The situation might be worse than (the situation) seems to be.

If interpreted in the second way above, omission of the subject is not allowed. This also seems to be the default interpretation with this construction.

It becomes much more acceptable if there is a complement after *be*:

> The situation might be worse than seems to be **the case**.

The reason it becomes more acceptable this way is that the omitted subject may no longer be understood as *the situation*.

> *The situation might be worse than **the situation** seems to be the case.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why the OP's sentence is unacceptable even though it "has an omitted subject that can be understood as an embedded clause".

Comment: Sure it does. It's the fact that though the embedded clause interpretation is (technically) possible, it's not the one chosen unless it's forced by the presence of a complement to _be_. Without that complement, it's interpreted like the example with _Liz_, and the subject is required in the comparative clause.

Comment: But the embedded clause interpretation is possible in (3''') of my answer even without any complement of _appears_. How would you distinguish that from the OP's sentence?

Comment: I'd say it's extraposition that's required in order to make the construction work; the impersonal construction - (a) in your answer - is unacceptable. The fact that _appear_ licenses constructions with no internal complement (apart from the impersonal construction), whereas _seems_ does not, likely accounts for the difference in acceptability - _the moon appeared_ vs _*the moon seemed_. Note that adding _to be_ into (3''') makes it significantly less acceptable as _be_ also requires an internal complement.

Comment: What do you mean (a) in my answer is unacceptable?

Comment: The version with dummy _it_ where _it_ has no meaning is not an acceptable interpretation for the comparative construction _than seems to be_. Your example (a) is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of *Comparative Deletion*, where a comparison is given or is implied. Therefore in such cases *ellipsis* is frequently seen. And this is what is happening in your sentence.

> The situation might be worse **than what seems to be [the situation/the case.]**

Please note that **what** functions as the subject of the comparative clause.

Comment: Are you sure the OP's sentence as is is correct?

Comment: @JK2 No. There's no clause without a subject, and the 'missing subject' in the OP's sentence is _what._

Answer (score 1):

> (1) ??*The situation might be worse than seems to be.*

I can't think of any context where (1) could work for me. Please state your source and/or at the very least why you think it's "correct".

The easiest fix I can think of is to add *it*:

> (2) *The situation might be worse than **it** seems to be.*

Note ***it*** here refers back to *the situation*, and that it's not dummy *it*. When ***it*** refers to *the situation* as in (2), ***it*** does not contain anything being compared, so ***it*** cannot be omitted.

There are two kinds of dummy *it*:

> (a) ***It** seems that the situation is bad.* [***It*** has no meaning.]
>
> (b) ***It** seems to be the case **that the situation is bad**.* [***It*** refers to an extraposed subject ***that the situation is bad***.]

If we're to use dummy *it*, we can say:

> (3) *The situation might be worse than **it** seems that the situation is.* [using (a)]
>
> (4) *The situation might be worse than **it** seems to be the case **that the situation is**.* [using (b)]

In (4), we should be able to omit dummy *it* if we also omit ***that the situation is***, because the *that*-clause contains what's being compared.

> (4') *The situation might be worse than seems to be the case.*

Since the dummy *it* in (a) doesn't specifically refer to the *that*-clause that contains what's being compared, it's questionable at best if we can omit the dummy *it* along with the *that*-clause in (3) as follows:

> (3') ?*The situation might be worse than seems.*

Adding some phrases like *at first glance*, *at first sight*, etc., however, might slightly increase its acceptability:

> (3'') ?*The situation might be worse than seems at first glance.*

Strangely, changing the verb to 'appear' appears to fix the problem:

> (3''') *The situation might be worse than appears at first glance.*